# Even numbers between 1 and 100 inclusive

Tags: java, while-loop, numbers

I need to display all the even numbers between 1-100 inclusive using a `while` loop. I couldn't mange it. I think it should be something like this :

```
int e = 1;
while (( 1 < e ) && ( e < 100 )) {
   e = e + 1;

   if (e % 2==0) {
      System.out.print(" " + e);
   }
}
```

Edit - I did it like this:

```
while ( e <= 100 ) { 
     e = e + 1;
     if ( e % 2 == 0)
     {   
         System.out.print(" " + e);
     }
}
```

Comment: If `e` is initially set to `1` then `1 < e` will never be true.

Comment: The `e = e + 1` should be the last sentence of the while loop, after the conditional, or you won't print `1`

Comment: @h3nr1x In this particular case that's not an issue, since 1 isn't an even number. Generally, though, you're correct; `e` should have its value modified at the very end of the body of the loop.

Comment: Why don't you start with e=2 and add 2 in every run?

Comment: You can replace `e = e + 1;` by `e++;`, it means the same thing.

Comment: A for loop would be a much better fit in this case. Strange choice for a while loop exercise.

Comment: I did it , while ( e <= 100 )
  {
   
   e = e +1;
   
   if ( e % 2 == 0)
   {
   
   System.out.print(" " + e);
   }

Answer (score 5):

Simple version:

```
int e = 2;
while (e <= 100) {
  System.out.print(" " + e);
  e += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to fix your while statement and move the adding:

```
while (e <= 100) {
  if (e % 2 == 0)
    System.out.println(e);
  e = e + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `while ( e <= 100 )` instead of `while (( 1 < e ) && ( e < 100 ))`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
while (( 1 <= e ) && ( e <= 100 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following

```
int i = 2;
while(i<=100)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
    i+=2;
}
```

OR you may use

```
int i = 1;
while(i<=100)
{
    if(i%2==0)
        printf("%d\n", i);
    i++;
}
```